# Could a car be slowed by the drive shaft?

Tags: brakes, alternator, hybrid

Could enough electromagnets be place around the drive shaft to slow a car and generate electricity? Or a switch that would engage electromagnets going down hill?  When you apply the brakes the drive shaft moves in range of the magnets mounted from the drive shaft housing. How would one try this?

[image]

Comment: This is basically how a stepper motor works. When power is off, the motor shaft spins freely. When it's on, and not receiving a signal to move, the magnets hold the shaft. If you try building this, make sure it doesn't lock up the drive shaft. Or take video and post it if it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and this exists, on buses and trucks due to size, its called an eddy brake or eddy current brake or electric retarder or induction brake.

Telma is one manufacturer for trucks and buses:

https://www.telma.com/produits/fonctionnement